# Excluding a field that has numbers in it, with regex for sql

Tags: sql, regex

I am trying to exclude any names that contain numbers from a query, but I seem to be way off in my attempts:

```
 SELECT * FROM products WHERE name not REGEX '[0-9]|'
```

I thought you could do regex with sql, what am I doing wrong? How can you exclude a field with any numbers?

Comment: Remove `|`, use `not REGEX '[0-9]'`

Comment: oh dear, a typo, cant believe I missed that

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @Source Yes, please do. And please mark the answer that works best for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some valid syntax.

MySQL (and SQLite if `REGEXP` has a supporting function):

```
WHERE name not REGEXP '[0-9]'
```

Oracle:

```
WHERE not regexp_like(name, '[0-9]')
```

Postgres:

```
WHERE NOT name ~ '[0-9]'
```

SQL Server:

```
WHERE name NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the alternation operator `|`:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE name not REGEX '[0-9]'
```

When you use `[0-9]|` regex, it matches a digit **or** an empty string. So, it will match any string.